# If character then redo the function

Tags: c

In C code.
This is the part I want to work on below. I want to be able to do... if a character value then say "not a number", however, because it is an array and it increments I'm not sure how to do such, newbie here, so please explain and show me an example how to do if possible. Have to enter up to 10 values.

So if:

Employee 1 = c

*"Not a Number. Try again."*

Employee 1 = 5

Employee 2 = 55

Employee 3 = g

*"Not a Number. Try again."*

Employee 3...etc

```
void getSalaries(float sal[], int size)
{
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {       
        printf("Enter salary for Employee #%d: ", i + 1);
        if (scanf("%f", &sal[i]) != 1)
        {
           printf ("Not a number. Please try again.\n");
           break;
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to repeat something, you need a loop. If you don't know how many times you'll want to loop in advance, it's probably going to be a `while` loop. The following structure will achieve your goal cleanly:

```
while (1) {
   printf("Enter salary for Employee #%d: ", i + 1);
   scanf("%f", &sal[i]);        
   if (...valid...)
      break;

   printf("Not a Number. Try again.\n");
}
```

The value returned by `scanf` will help you determine if the input was valid. I will leave consulting the documentation and finishing that part of your homework to you.

Comment: how do i say if character though? and declare such?

Comment: See the addition I made to my answer

Comment: you put while (1) how do i implement the (i = 0; i < size; i++).. will i need to use do while loop here?

Comment: You keep that. You still want to get the salary of each employee.

Comment: so this is what i have so far, am i on the right track? what do i need to change?

Comment: No. You *also* want to loop until you get a correct answer. You want *both* loops. Think about how it would be phrased in English: *For* each employee, *until* a correct value is provided, ask the employee's salary. Two levels of looping.

Comment: may i please get an extra hint seems not to be working when i put while loop it just consistently says try again despite having a nested second loop

Comment: @sam, there is a problem with scanf. Input that doesnt match your format string stays in the buffer until next call, you need to "eat" that "bad string" from the buffer before you can continue.

Answer (score 1):

Some help to get you started, [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) returns the number of successfully read items (matching % marks in format string).  So you can evaluate this number and take action accordingly.

```
int n=scanf("%f", &sal[i]);  
if (n !=1){
  // do something here 
}
```

**Hint:** There is a common problem with using scanf,in that it wont recover from a "bad" input, unless you empty the buffer by "eating" the bad string.

If you want to convince your teacher that you have a VERY BIG BRAIN /s, you could do something like this;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void getSalaries (float sal[], int size)
{

  char *scan_fmt[2] = {
    "%f",           // Get float
    "%*s%f"         // Eat previous bad input, and get float
  };
  char *cli_mess[2] = {
    "Enter salary for Employee #%d: ",
    "Try again, for Employee #%d: "
  };


  for (int i = 0, n=1; i < size; i += n==1){
      printf (cli_mess[n!=1], i + 1);
      n = scanf (scan_fmt[n!=1], &sal[i]);
  }
}


int main ()
{
  float s[3];
  getSalaries (s, 3);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: this works wow very nice, is this the only way to do it? i have never used cli_mess before

Comment: @sam, no there are many ways to do it. cli_mess is just the name of the char* array.  Try to take what you have learned here (eating bad input from scanf, the fact that scanf returns number of matches) and try to create your own solution based on the concepts that were already familiar to you.

Comment: however when you enter 2r a number with a letter it still reads the value

Comment: how would you go about fixing the number with letter ?

Comment: @sam , I am actually not sure that that is possible.  This is where the rabbit hole gets deeper, and you you need to dig out  sscanf 
 http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/   and friends.